# MySQL select datetime for expired subscriptions

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, select

I have a table called "subscriptions" with these columns:

- id
- client_id
- date
- expiring

I would like to select all values that their subscriptions are expired and they don't have any ongoing subscriptions.

For example I have these records in this table:

**id | client_id | date | expiring**
1 | 23 | 2015-07-07 08:26:08 | 2015-07-27 08:26:08
2 | 23 | 2015-07-10 08:26:08 | 2015-07-15 08:26:08
3 | 21 | 2015-07-14 08:26:08 | 2015-07-15 08:26:08

That means the result should show me client with ID 21 but not the client with ID 23 since he has an active subscription.

I hope i explained it well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: multiple lines in DB with the same id... ? Can you be more specific, with full and precise examples please ?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, each id is unique like 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM subscriptions 
WHERE client_id NOT IN (
    SELECT client_id FROM subscriptions 
    WHERE expiring > NOW())
```

Comment: I tried it and it shows me both clients... I want to exclude clients like id 23 since they have an active membership

Comment: @Andr you mean id=2 should be shown since id=1 isn't, and they have the same client_id ? If so, just change "id" with "client_id" in this query (so twice)

Comment: my bad :) it's client_id indeed, I've just approved @Random edit